# Jquery - send post attributes to another domain

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to send POST attributes from client to server in another domain.

Since simple json dataType won't work in a cross domain,
i've tried with JSONP

```
<script>
var lookup = {'username':'admin'}

$.ajax({
    url: "https://somesite.com/router.php",
    type: "post",    
    data: JSON.stringify(lookup),   
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    failure: alert("failed")
});
</script>
```

But then it send it as GET and not POST.
This is how it looks like in Fiddler:

```
Request URL: https://somesite.com/router.php?callback=jQuery172016627637017518282_1429096551228&{%22username%22:%22admin%22}&_=1429096552070
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500

Query Url
callback: jQuery172016627637017518282_1429096551228
_: 1429096552070
```

So how can i send this paramter (username=admin) to a cross domain as POST?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must add `method: 'POST'` to your ajax call otherwise jQuery appends your `data` object to the URL (GET parameters)

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: You can see the - type: "post" , so it should be send as POST

Answer (score 0):

You can send request from controller or configure target server to accept request.

i.e. in .htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</ifModule>
```

Comment: To send request from your  controller still you can use ajax `url: "/path/to/method",`, then send request and return response to ajax

Comment: Thanks, but i have no control on the server side.

Comment: Then, like I said, you can send request from your controller without configuring server. Just add action doing this in your controller, and use ajax to run this action.